# How can I target push notifications to both iPhone and Android?

Tags: iphone, android, notifications, push

I am developing apps for both Android and iPhone, and am looking for how I can push notifications to both (if you only have an answer for one, that's ok, I'm sure someone has an answer for the other).

For example, if I'm having a special on something and want to notify people so it sort of dings and a message pops up (I have a Groupon app that does that) how can I accomplish this? And do I have to reprogram each time, or can I do it through an RSS or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Android 2.2+ use [C2DM](http://code.google.com/android/c2dm/).  Apple also has a [proprietary push notification service](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Push_Notification_Service).  In both cases you need to register with the company to use the system.  Also in both cases you will need a web server able to communicate to Google and Apple.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to have to support an entire server framework for communicating with both iOS and Android devices, take a look at [UrbanAirship](http://urbanairship.com/). It's a dirt-cheap service that allows you to push both plain- and rich- text messages to iOS, Android, and BlackBerry.

**Gravy:** It also has mechanisms for In-App Purchasing, and statistics tracking.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe PushOver can be a solution https://pushover.net/ but there is probably other web services like that !